# Assigning objects to a class from a large list and printing each of them?

Tags: python, oop, object, methods

I have a file containing 3331 rugby matches that has 9 attributes about each match per line, they are;

(date, day, year, team_1, team_2, team_1_score, team_2_score, team_1_tries, team_2_tries, neutral).

Sample data:

```
15 Feb 1875, Mon, 1875, ENG, IRE, 7, 0, 2, 0, N
08 Mar 1875, Mon, 1875, SCO, ENG, 0, 0, 0, 0, N
13 Dec 1875, Mon, 1875, IRE, ENG, 0, 4, 0, 2, N
```

I created a class called Match to store this data, and I tried to implement a  method to print the data for each match, here's what I have for that;

```
class Match:

def __init__(self, date, day, year, team_1, team_2, team_1_score, team_2_score, team_1_tries, team_2_tries, neutral):
    self.date=date
    self.day=day
    self.year=year
    self.team_1=team_1
    self.team_2=team_2
    self.team_1_score=team_1_score
    self.team_2_score=team_2_score
    self.team_1_tries=team_1_tries
    self.team_2_tries=team_2_tries
    self.neutral=neutral

def show(self):
    print("Date: " + self.date /n +
         "Day: " + self.day /n +
         "Year: " + self.year/n + 
         "Home Team :" + self.team_1 /n +
         "Home Team Score: " + self.team_1_score /n +
         "Home Team Tries: " + self.team_1_tries /n +
         "Away Team: " + self.team_2 /n +
         "Away Team Score: " + self.team_2_score /n +
         "Away Team Tries: " + self.team_2_tries /n +
         "Neutrality: " + self.neutral /n)
```

This part is where I think I'm running into trouble, we have to actually go through my file ("RugbyResultsData.csv") and create an object for each match, our lecturer gave us all the code apart from one line we need to adjust, but I'm not sure where to go with this, this is a first year introduction to programming course, and I'm not in a CS related degree per-se (Mathematics).

```
#Adjust this code to create a list of Match objects

matches = list()
count = 0
with open('RugbyResultsData.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split(',')

        match = #Adjust code here

        matches.append(match)
        count = count + 1

print(str(count) + " matches loaded")`
```

Where it says "Adjust code here" I tried to do list(words) which can get me each line of the match, but I don't know how to turn that data into objects. After that I need to iterate through each element of the class and print it.

Any help is appreciated, sorry if this is a nooby question

Comment: Try `match = Match(*words)`...

Comment: @EdWard It tells me I'm missing 9 required positional arguments, the specific ones I listed above

Comment: Can you give us an sample of the first few lines from the csv?

Comment: 15 Feb 1875 Mon 1875 ENG IRE         7 0 2 0     N
08 Mar 1875 Mon 1875 SCO ENG        0 0 0 0     N
13 Dec 1875 Mon 1875 IRE         ENG 0 4 0 2     N

Comment: My formatting is awful, but the "dd mmm yyyy" is all one cell in the csv

Comment: I submitted an edit to put your sample data into the question content, although I made the assumption it's comma separated (since it comes from a csv). Based on your comment though, does your data actually _have_ commas?

Comment: To clarify, If I run your code using the sample data (with commas) and @EdWard's suggestion, everything works. If I change the split character, i.e. `words = line.split('*')`, the code fails with the 9 missing positional arguments you mentioned (since there's no * to split on).

Comment: @b_c my data doesn't actually **have** commas in the csv, but when I open the file and print each line then commas appear

Comment: That's what's causing the positional arguments error then. Do you know what delimiter is separating your data? CSV will typically use `,`, but Tabs (`\t`), semicolons (`;`) and pipes (`|`) are also common. Also "when I open the file and print each line then commas appear" - this confuses me. Comma's shouldn't just appear, unless what you're printing is a list/tuple/etc.

Comment: I think I've made progress (I hope), after applying @EdWard's suggestion like you said and creating a line directly after in the loop saying `match.show()` I'm getting an error now that says `NameError: name 'n' is not defined` , and it's highlighting the lines `"Neutrality: " + self.neutral /n)` and `match.show()`

Comment: Ok yes, you're just about there then :) You do have multiple syntax errors in your `show()` method - the `\n`'s shouldn't be there.

Comment: @b_c It's finally worked! Thanks to the two of you for helping me! The /n's were there to try and put each statement on a new line, but it doesn't seem to want to take that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
class Match:
    def __init__(self, date, day, year, team_1, team_2, team_1_score, team_2_score, team_1_tries, team_2_tries, neutral):
        self.date=date
        self.day=day
        self.year=year
        self.team_1=team_1
        self.team_2=team_2
        self.team_1_score=team_1_score
        self.team_2_score=team_2_score
        self.team_1_tries=team_1_tries
        self.team_2_tries=team_2_tries
        self.neutral=neutral

    def show(self):
        print(
            "\n".join((
                "Date: " + self.date,
                "Day: " + self.day,
                "Year: " + self.year,
                "Home Team :" + self.team_1,
                "Home Team Score: " + self.team_1_score,
                "Home Team Tries: " + self.team_1_tries,
                "Away Team: " + self.team_2,
                "Away Team Score: " + self.team_2_score,
                "Away Team Tries: " + self.team_2_tries,
                "Neutrality: " + self.neutral
            ))
        )


matches = list()
count = 0

with open('RugbyResultsData.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line[:-1].split(',')

        match = Match(*words)

        matches.append(match)
        count = count + 1

print(str(count) + " matches loaded")
```

As @b_c pointed out, the error was in `show`.